# CSS Selector for not a child of element type?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to style `code` elements that are not inside `a` tags.

What is the best approach to accomplish this?

`code:not(a code)` doesn't seem to work at all, at least on Chrome, even though it [seems like it should](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/:not)

I can't get it to work from the console either.

Are there any other css-only approaches I could use for this?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

`:not` does not support combinator selectors.

If we're talking about its direct parent:

```
:not(a) > code
```

Otherwise there's no way to do this in CSS. You'll have to override it:

```
code {
    /* some styles */
}

a code {
    /* override previous styles */
}
```

Comment: the issue there is that I didn't want to use a star selector

Comment: Out of curiosity: I have no idea why, but `:not(a) > code` worked, while `:not(a) code` didn't, any idea why? (still chrome)

Comment: @Nico - Because `:not(a) code` looks for *any ancestor* that is not an `a`, which is always true. `:not(a) > code` only looks at the immediate parent.

Comment: Jackpot, I should've though of that.

Comment: I noted that also a combination in the parenthesys works. I used a combinator like this combinator selector:  `:not(figure >p ) > img {width: 6cm}` to style img in "Joplin" (an html/markdown notetaking software that export in html.

Answer (score 33):

Actually, you should be able to use your code , or you could use the wildcard character to select all elements to not be selected

```
code:not(a *) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/jkohlin/pen/OJmVXEO)

Comment: This is actually working and the best solution, if I want to prevent a CSS reset to be applied inside certain containers, for example. Thanks!

Comment: Why this works? I expected :not to apply to selected element not it's parent

Comment: @MaciejKozieja  `code` matches all `<code>` elements, but then, `:not` filters out all elements matching the selector `a *` , excluding them from the list. The rest, e.g. `<p><code>` will get styled.

Comment: So it runs two queries and selects `A - B`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: This should definitely be the selected answer!

Answer (score 3):

Confirmed it works now at 2023 I think.

```
h1:not(.original-style h1){
    /*This will applies for every h1 tag which was not in .original-style at any level*/
}
```