# CSS Selector: Finding elements NOT child of another element

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to find all elements that are NOT inside another element with CSS selector?

```
// finding all links with class test
var a = document.querySelectorAll('a.test');

// finding all links with class test insode div class box
var a = document.querySelectorAll('div.box a.test');

// finding all links with class test that are NOT inside div class box (not working)
var a = document.querySelectorAll(':not(.box) a.test');
var a = document.querySelectorAll('div:not(.box) a.test');
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900763/css-selector-for-not-a-child-of-element-type

Comment: @Markai .. Thanks .. I had my fingers crossed but no luck ;)