# Select All Elements Except elements with a specific class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the css below:

```
:not(.myid_templates_editor_element ){
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    font: 11px/16px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #444;
}
```

I want to select all elements in the page except the element together with its children with the class `myid_templates_editor_element`. My code above does not work. How will I do that using css?

Comment: We need the html in order to make it work, consider using http://jsfiddle.com for this.

Comment: One thing to note is that you're selecting only the parent and not its children. Not all properties of the parent are inherited by the children. Other than that, I can't see anything wrong. When you say *does not work* it is always better to indicate in what way it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

I need the HTML in order to solve that problem. I can think on a possible case:

You are using some CSS framework and your own styles file is *before* the framework css file.

In that case, you should fix that or try

```
:not(.myid_templates_editor_element){
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    list-style-type: none !important;
    font: 11px/16px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
    color: #444 !important;
}
```

**Anyway, what you want to do is a really bad practice.**

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to apply a rule to each element in your DOM tree except `.myid_templates_editor_element` and it's children (`.myid_templates_editor_element *`).

However, CSS `:not` [does not support combination selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900763/css-selector-for-not-a-child-of-element-type), so something like `:not(.myid_templates_editor_element):not(.myid_templates_editor_element *)` is not possible.

You will need to find a workaround, i.e. by setting your rules to all elements, then resetting for certain ones:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    font: 11px/16px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #444;
}

.myid_templates_editor_element,
.myid_templates_editor_element * {
    margin: auto;
    padding: auto;
    ...
}
```

[Here's an example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ad4kmtwa/2/) using border-color.

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
color:red

}
:not(.myid_templates_editor_element){
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    font: 11px/16px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
    first apply
</div>
<span>
first apply
</span>
<ul>
    <li>first apply</li>
</ul>
<div class="myid_templates_editor_element">
    not to apply on me
</div>
```